# Simplest way to test JavaScript code (for web-frontend) on each Git push

Tags: javascript, git, testing, continuous-integration, web-frontend

I'm looking for the simplest most minimalist way to create automated tests on each Git push for a relatively simple JavaScript code (on GitHub) for an HTML/CSS/JS web application, in a way that it can also test the HTML elements (via JS manipulation).

I assume it would need some sort of a "headless browser" testing - in which case I would only need it to be executed in Google Chrome. (This application is not planned be used in any other browser.)

I already created a JS function that does the testing. This function should be executed after the entire application (web page) is loaded (HTML, CSS, JS), since it involves the manipulation of HTML elements. For the sake of a simple example, let's say I always expect an even number that is larger than 5. The number is, say, the count of paragraph elements in one of the div elements on the application's HTML page. In that case the function would be:

```
function my_test() {
    var is_valid = true;
    var num = $("#my_div").find("p").length; // (JQuery is included in the app)
    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        console.log("it's not an even number");
        is_valid = false;
    } else if (num <= 5) {
        console.log("it's smaller than 5");
        is_valid = false;
    }
    return is_valid ;
}
```

**So the question is, what would be the simplest way to make this test automatically be run in the terminal whenever `git push` is executed (by anyone who wants to contribute to the repository)?**

I know that there are Node.js testing frameworks such as Tape, but it seems complicated for what I imagine (or hope) could be done simpler; plus if I install these it adds MBs to the otherwise tiny application (around 0.3 MB) which I don't really like.

Such testing could then be automatically run with e.g. Travis, so for example I could just add a ".travis.yml" file, with

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- "node"
```

And then in the package.json file I could add e.g. the line `"test": "jshint my_code.js"` to test the my_code.js with the jshint package.

But is there a way to execute my own simple JS function as a test? E.g., to say "**first load my page (HTML, CSS) with all my related JS code, then execute my custom `my_test()` function (above), display (in the terminal) whatever would be output in the console (via `console.log('output')`), and, if in the end it does not return `true`, disrupt the git push**".

I appreciate any suggestions, but the best would be a clear description of what steps should be taken to set all this up. E.g., "create the .travis.yml with such and such content, add the package.json file with such and such content, etc.". And/or if it's perhaps also possible to use e.g. Tape without installing it on top of the application, but just automatically calling it whenever the testing is executed, then how would that be done.

(I don't insist on Travis or Tape at all, these were just examples.)

(**UPDATE:** I now accepted my own solution - for lack of a better one - but if someone can offer a simpler/better one, I will change the accepted answer.)

Comment: By `git push` do you mean to run the code on your computer? If so, look into git hooks: https://githooks.com.

Comment: No, it should be an automatic test for anyone contributing to the code (to the GitHub repository). I edited my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, though not too simple. I used Travis, Karma, and a very basic Jasmine code.

First, you need to have a package.json file in the root of the application with this content:

```
{
  "name": "CITapp",
  "description": "Concealed Information Test app",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "*",
    "karma": "*",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "*",
    "karma-fixture": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "*",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "*"
  }
}
```

If you now run `npm install` in the terminal at the path of the app, every required module will be added to the app (under node_modules folder). (For this, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) has to be first installed on the PC.) This is only needed for local testing (on your own PC), but Travis does this installation automatically on their server on each `git push` (see below). (These modules occupy quite some space, so they are better not included in the app, e.g. in the repository in particular.)

For Travis, you just need a .travis.yml file with:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "stable"
```

Now, in the package.json file there was this line `"test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js --single-run"`. This directs the "test" command to the karma.conf.js under the test directory in the app. This file should contain something like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', // JQuery from the root's js folder
      '../js/my_scripts.js', // personal scripts from the root's js folder
      'add_html.js', // from same folder as the karma.conf.js
      'test.js' // from the same folder as the karma.conf.js
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--enable-logging',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--no-first-run',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-translate',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
                '--disable-device-discovery-notifications',
                '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
                '--disable-web-security'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity

  })
}
```

Most importantly, I used the framework `jasmine`, initiated `ChromeHeadless` (with some special `flags` because otherwise it gives errors), and loaded my files in the list of `files : [...]`.

The add_html.js file adds HTML to the page via JS code, e.g. as (following the example in the question):

```
var fixture = "<div id='my_div'><p>paragraph1</p><p>paragraph2</p></div>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', fixture);
```

(For some reason, when I try to load HTML directly via the Karma files list, it doesn't work - but inserting it like this is fine for me as well.)

Finally, the test with Jasmine in the `test.js` is as simple as this:

```
describe("suite", function() {
  it("check if my_test() returns true", function() {
    expect( my_test() ).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Note that the function `my_test()` comes from the (hypothetical) my_scripts.js file - possibly identical to the one in the question's example - so it's defined as a simple pure (well, only JQuery added) JS script. Whenever the script returns true, the Jasmine test will pass. If it does not return true (including any unrelated errors that stop the execution of the test code), the test will fail.

This can all be tested locally using the `npm test` command from the terminal at the path of the app (again, for this, first all required Node.js packages have to be installed).

Now the last thing to do is to connect Travis CI to the repository, which is just a few very simple steps; see their [GitHub tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/). This will create a dedicated Travis site connected to the given GitHub repository.

Then it's all done. On each push, Travis will build up the page in a headless ("invisible") Chrome browser and run the `my_test()` function, sending optional notifications if it fails. Each message via `console.log()` in this function (or in any other function of the app that is executed during testing) is shown on the Travis site. A further nice thing is that if you want the testing to stop at a certain point (e.g. if some conditions are not met), you can simply write `throw "this and this condition was not met"`, which also stops the Travis test at that point, showing this error message.

For my actual implementation, see: https://github.com/gasparl/citapp_pc
(There are some additions of course, but the logic is the same.)

Answer (score 4):

Git has hooks that allow running different tasks when something occurs.
In this case, you need to add logic in the **pre-push** hook

Sample pre-push script: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample

1. Edit your hooks in `.git/hooks/pre-push`
2. The script used for git hooks can be made in any scripting language, so in this case, you will use your js code.
3. Do not forget to add the shebang for node

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

4. Make sure to return a non-zero respond if you want to stop the push.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - still, there are 2 problems with this. First, as I understand, these Git hooks cannot be automatically used by new contributors (i.e. others who fork/clone, modify, and push the code back). Second, it's nice that I can execute JS code, but I still don't know how I would load HTML (whose manipulation is part of the test).

Comment: @gaspar about the 2 problems:

**1. Share the hooks**
The hooks can be shared in projects o the git repository. You can have a setup command that will copy your hooks to collaborators .git folder, is a best practice in fact when you have setup for hooks. That way, any new collaborator when they run the install of your project will get the pre-push on its own .git hooks.

**2. Manipulate the DOM**
When I read your questions, it was not mentioning the HTML, if you need to interact with DOM, the best way will be using a test framework, but you mentioned you do not want to do it.

Comment: 1: OK, true, that could work, though it seems slightly fussy for new contributors.
2: I mean no offense at all, and I apologize for being unclear, but I did say (in bold font) even in the very first version that the test should "first load my page" (not just JS). Also, the very title says "JavaScript code (for web-frontend)" (so, again, not just JS). And I definitely did not say I "do not want to do it". Anyway, sorry for the confusion, it should now be clear with my edited question.
In sum, again, I appreciate your answer but it's not the right solution for me.